# Problems with configuring Apache for mobile website

Tags: linux, apache, mobile, web

I am having some trouble with configuring Apache for a website that has both a normal and mobile version. The idea was to redirect the user with a mobile browser automatically to the mobile version and if someone on a normal desktop PC is trying to connect to the mobile version to redirect it to the normal website.

Right now it redirects a mobile user to the mobile website correctly. But it is seems to be unable to redirect the other way to the desktop version. Also, when you go to the mobile version of the website, it displays the default "It works!" page instead of the mobile index page for some reason..

Here is all the configuration that I used. Hopefully someone is able to help me out with this. Thanks in advance! 
Normal website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@henal.local
ServerName henal.local
ServerAlias www.henal.local

DocumentRoot /var/www/henal.local
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/henal.local>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/deltionkrant/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel debug

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/deltionkrant/access.log combined

     Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess normal website:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-  mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ http://m.henal.local/ [L,R=302]
```

Mobile website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@henal.local
ServerName m.henal.local
ServerAlias henal.local

DocumentRoot /var/www/henal.local/mobile
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/henal.local/mobile>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess mobile webiste:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|googlebot- mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.henal.local/ [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - so you are trying to do content negotiation here and you are regexing on the user agent. Aside from the rewrtile rules you have, you need to consider the following:

1. Using the [Apache Mobile Filter](http://www.apachemobilefilter.org/) instead of a Regex. It is more accurate and provides a greater range of features
2. You should allow users to choose the representation/experience that they want. So if you are presenting them with the mobile version, then you should let them choose the desktop version instead since this might actually have been what they wanted; and vice versa.
3. This could be for a plethora of reasons e.g they have bookmarks to the desktop, someone shared a url to the desktop version etc. etc. Your content negotiation technique is pretty basic and doesn't take into consideration any of these use cases.

Having considered this, specific to your problems above:

Try removing the quotes from your RewriteCond patterns and add the R=302 and L flag to make sure now other rewrite directives are executed. i.e:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot- mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos) [NC,R=302,L]
```

Secondly its likely that you are seeing the default desktop "it works" because you are testing on a desktop browser and being redirected to the desktop host.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is mostly a school demonstration so it's not going to be used for a public website (though I might create a better solution with your tips here for my real public sites!). That's also why I am configuring it like this.

 Really appreciate your tips though and will take those points for future projects. :)

Comment: But I tried removing the quotes and added the 2 flags to the .htaccess. I tested it again but it that didn't make any difference. About the "it works" page, yes I am testing it with the Browser on the machine where I configured Apache on (virtual Ubuntu). I edited the hosts file so that henal.local and m.henal.local refer to 127.0.0.1 so maybe that's the cause? Although the normal website seems to work just fine..

Comment: ok, so you need to test with a mobile browser. With the above configuration, if you enter m.henal.local into your desktop browser, then its going to redirect to henal.local. Since your DNS is not externally resolvable, then you won't be able to use your mobile phone to test. Instead, why not try the Android Emulator: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html

Comment: p.s +1 for doing a school demonstration

Answer (score 0):

Slight tangent, in response to William Greenly's 
"Since your DNS is not externally resolvable, then you won't be able to use your mobile phone to test."

FYI Pagekite (http://pagekite.net/) makes it easy to expose localhost to the net, in order to facilitate testing stuff on your dev machine from your phone.

HTH someone out there.